# Can Unity's WebView play WebGL games?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl, cocos2d-js

I'm part of a team porting old WebGL / Cocos2D-JS games into Unity games, but since there's a lot of them, it's taking awhile.

So one of them asks, why not just use Unity's webview ([as can be seen here](https://github.com/gree/unity-webview)) to show the WebGL games while the Unity versions are under construction?

I went ahead and tried that, running off a PC with Prepros hosting some web games created with Cocos2D, which is then accessed by a link in Unity.

Unfortunately, all I get is a black page (the same web view can open google just fine, for example).

Maybe I'm just doing something wrong, but I'd like to know if this is even possible in the first place.

The objective is to get Unity to play WebGL games on phones while the actual mobile versions of those games are under construction. Can it be done?

Comment: It depends really, does the access link require a specific version of HTML viewer? Does it require a plug-in? Does the WebView actually contain these items? The answer can change dependent on these.

Comment: @DHansen, since the games are Cocos2D-JS, I assumed nothing else was necessary. Upon re-checking though, while I can open google, I can't type anything in the search bar.

Comment: Does seem then that JS may not be enabled, or very limited. The last item I used for a similar thing was uWebKit (viewing analytics in game), which had a licence fee. However this is now discontinued. Generally putting a game into another game via this method can cause you many issues and should be avoided if possible.